# Measures with Multiple Categories to Compute New Column in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Need to compute several measures to compute values for a new column in Power BI.
My data is structured like this:

```
Col1  Col2   Col3  Col4  
 A    Type1   2     4
 B    Type2   5     9
 A    Type3   9     12
 B    Type1   4     2
 A    Type3   1     2
 B    Type2   9     8
 A    Type2   7     3
```

I'm trying to find the proportion or 'share' of the difference of Col4 and Col3 per each category 1 and 2. For example, Col5 for row1 would compute the difference of Col4 and Col3 divided by the total of all Type1 AND A differences sum(Col4)-sum(Col3) to give the proportion. Ultimately, I want something like this:

```
Col1  Col2   Col3  Col4  Col5
 A    Type1   2     4     66.6%
 B    Type2   5     9    133.3%
 A    Type2   9     12   -300%
 B    Type1   4     2     100%
 A    Type1   1     2    33.3%
 B    Type2   9     8   -33.3%
 A    Type2   7     3     400%
```

(e.g. all values in Col5 where Col2 = Type1 AND Col1 = 'A' should sum to 100%)

Given this data, I tried to create a measure 'Total' that was sum(Col4)-sum(Col3) (using proper PowerBI notation for column references) then created a new column Col5 hoping to apply that to each category such that: Col5 = (Col4-Col3)/'Total'

But, I got something like this:

```
Col1  Col2   Col3  Col4  Col5
 A    Type1   2     4     0%
 B    Type2   5     9    -100%
 A    Type3   9     12    0%
 B    Type1   4     2    -100%
 A    Type3   1     2     0%
 B    Type2   9     8    -100%
 A    Type2   7     3    -100%
```

When I try to use a quick measure, it can only do one categorization (i.e. *either* Col1 OR Col2) - but I want to classify totals by both at once.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Please try this one!

```
Col5 =
VAR Tbl =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( YourTable, YourTable[Col1], YourTable[Col2] ),
        "RowTotal", SUMX ( YourTable, [Col4] - [Col3] ),
        "GroupTotal",
            CALCULATE (
                SUMX ( YourTable, [Col4] - [Col3] ),
                ALLEXCEPT ( YourTable, YourTable[Col1], YourTable[Col2] )
            )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX ( Tbl, DIVIDE ( [RowTotal], [GroupTotal] ) )
```

[image: GMH ResultSET]